# How to call Master Detail Page from Content page

Tags: xamarin

I'm creating an app using Xamarin Forms where when a user launches an app for the first time, they are sent to a login page. Once they log in, they're redirected to the MasterPage, which is a MasterDetail Page.How to call Master Detail Page from Content page.

Comment: Did you tried `Navigation.PushModalAsync(new YourPage());`?

Comment: I try with Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage())..It does not work.I think Navigation is for Content not for MasterPage??

Comment: Can you tell me what issue you are getting while using `PushAsync`? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Error is System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage..

Comment: Please refer to my answer, that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, first you need to wrap your `LoginPage` inside `NavigationPage` as below:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
```

From your `LoginPage` you can now call MasterDetailPage as:

```
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MasterDetailPage());
```